# Tablesorter - days of the week

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm trying to get tablesorter to list the days of the week in correct order in a column. It currently just sorts them alphabetically. I gather a custom parser is one possible approach but I've had no luck in getting this to work after looking at the examples on the tablesorter website.

I've searched high and low on forums and blogs but can't seem to find anyone who has covered this specifically. I'm guessing it's probably a fairly simple solution for a developer but is proving a big headache for me as a designer with very limited knowledge of this area.

Any help or advice would be hugely helpful,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try adding a parser like this guy does in here: http://jsbin.com/enata/edit

here is an article too:
http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2008/09/29/jquery-tablesorter-list-of-builtin-parserssorters/

Comment: Thanks for your reply, appreciated. I'll try and work out if that first example might work for me. The blog article you quoted I found already, it's very helpful but couldn't seem to find if any of the existing parsers would work for week days (I even posted a request on that very page)